# Saving and later importing xls, csv files in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application, have implemented a facility seeing the railscast video http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel, that will directly import and update the db at same time, but it is creating problems when the file is too large.

So I want to write a facility to upload a csv or excel file in my application and save it in a directory. Then I want to add some kind of observer that will observe the contents of the directory and on an event like create or update of a file in that directory will trigger contents of those files to be uploaded in db. I am getting no idea about how to approach this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Joy I didn't see any comments from you on the answers... did any of those were what you were looking for?

Comment: No. Actually I don't want to use Resque. I was looking for something so that csv data is imported on event like updation and creation of a file in a certain directory in which file is being uploaded.

Comment: Why not Resque, (or any worker gem)? The solution you're looking for will have to involve some kind of polling on the filesystem, which is a bad idea unless you don't have any better alternatives. In any case, if you'd like to get an answer for what you need, can you add that you don't any type of workers on the **Update** section of the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best approach is to use [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) to import and convert in a worker separately from the request.

Suppose you have a controller to add the Excel file, which I'm going to call `Information` model:

```
class InformationController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @information = Information.new(params[:information])
    if @information.save
      resque = Resque.enqueue(ImportDataJob, @information.id)
      redirect_to @information, :notice => "Successfully created information for further processing."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

You'll need make a job, in this case `ImportDataJob`:

```
class ImportDataJob
  def self.perform(information_id)
    information = Information.find(information_id)
    # convert information.raw_csv or wherever attribute you saved the Excel or CSV into
    # and save it into the database where you need to
  end
end
```

You'll find a full tutorial in [Resque RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque?view=asciicast), where it shows how to add Resque into your existing Rails app.

**Note:** There's a conflict between README and the actual implementation for Resque. Apparently they want to change the way Resque is called (which is in the readme), but is not implemented yet. See this [Issue in Github](https://github.com/resque/resque/issues/1147) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Resque (and i do think doing it in a background job is the best approach), see also Spawnling, previously known as Spawn:

https://github.com/tra/spawnling

Super-low maintenance. In your controller action do something like

```
@file = <uploaded file here>
spawn do 
  #perform some long-running process using @file, in a new process
end
#current thread carries on straight away.
```

If you need to test if it's finished (or crashed for that matter) you can save the id of the new process like so:

```
@file = <uploaded file here>
spawner = spawn do 
  #perform some long-running process using @file, in a new process
end

#current thread carries on straight away.

spawner = spawn do
  #make it in a temp file so serve_if_present doesn't serve a halfmade file
  FileUtils.rm @filename if File.exists?(@filename)
  temp_filename = "#{@filename}.temp"
  ldb "temp_filename = #{temp_filename}"
  current_user.music_service.build_all_schools_and_users_xls(:filename => temp_filename)
  FileUtils.mv temp_filename, @filename
end
@spawn_id = spawner.handle
```

Comment: In answer to the (seemingly gone) comment about Heroku- it seems like Resque will work on Heroku (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407359/solution-for-background-jobs-on-heroku), i'm not sure about spawn.  If Heroku is a factor then i think you should modify your question to say this is for a Heroku-hosted app.

Comment: Max Williams - it was me, but I wasn't sure my question was relevant. Thanks so much!